# Steady state properties M/M/Inf/1/N queue

Tags: probability, markov-process, queueing

Say I have a fixed population size of $N$ individuals, each with exponential arrival times $\lambda$ to an infinite number of queues with exponential service times $\mu$.

I think the transition rate matrix should be something like this:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-N\lambda &N \lambda& & & & \\
\mu & -(\mu + (N-1)\lambda)& (N-1)\lambda & &\\
& 2\mu & -(2\mu + (N-2)\lambda)) & (N-2)\lambda & \\
& & 3\mu & -(3\mu + (N-3)\lambda)) &(N-3)\lambda & \\
& & & & & ... & \\
\end{array}\right)
$$

Is it possible to find a closed form solution for the average and the standard deviation of number of individuals being served?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each individual is either being served or not being served and the proportion of time they are being served is $p=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}$.  So the expected number being served in the stable distribution is $Np = \frac{N\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}$

Since the individuals are independent, the stable distribution of the number being served at a point in time is a binomial random variable with parameters $N$ and $p  =\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}$ so with mean $Np = \frac{N\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}$ and variance $Np(1-p) =  \frac{N\lambda\mu}{(\lambda+\mu)^2}$

It gets a little more complicated if you start with nobody being served, but the same binomial approach will work if you find $p_t$ for the probability that an individual is being served at time $t$

Comment: Ahh I missed the obvious fact that the processing of each individual is independent.  So simple then.  Thanks!